# how to use cell value as index

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell

I have an row array `X`, and a cell `C = {[1 3 4] [2 6]}`. I want to use `C` as index to get corresponding value from `x. The result should be`{[x(1) x(3) x(4)] [x(2) x(6)]}`. I tried`x(C)` but it doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

use cell2mat first http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html
you  may also need to reshape

```
>> C = {[1 3 4] [2 6]}
C =     
    [1x3 double]    [1x2 double]
>> A = cell2mat(C)
A =
     1     3     4     2     6
```

now you can adress x(C), or in one line

```
Y=x(cell2mat(C))
```

Comment: But I want the result also be a cell having the same structure as C

Answer (score 1):

```
result = mat2cell(x([C{:}]), 1, cellfun(@numel, C));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one-line way to perform this addressing:

```
Y = X([C{:}]);
```

**EDIT**

As you want the same cell structure as C, here is a second solution:

```
Y = cellfun(@(a) X(a),C,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: But this puts Y as an array, not as a cell with the same structure of C

Answer (score 0):

Per **Bentoy13**'s suggestion just do this:

```
cell(cellfun(@(a) x(a)',C,'UniformOutput',false))
```